# How do I make a dynamic for loop for the following code in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying yo make a for loop for a couple of blocks that are repetitive, however, some of their values differ with respect to x y positions, how do I make them such that I can still use a for loop and somehow manage distinct x y positions within the for loop .Here is my code :

```
m_views.add(hm7);

        HeatMapElementView hm8 = (HeatMapElementView)view.findViewById(R.id.hmEle_08);
        hm8.setTag(new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(4),Integer.valueOf(2)});
        hm8.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View vw){
                        if(isAnimating)
                            return;

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)m_hoverCraft.getLayoutParams();

                        //int xColumn = ((Integer[])vw.getTag())[0].intValue();
                        relParams.leftMargin = ((int)vw.getX())+((int)vw.getWidth()) - 450;
                        int yRow = ((Integer[])vw.getTag())[1].intValue();
                        relParams.topMargin = ((int)(vw.getHeight()*yRow) - (vw.getHeight()/2) - 162);

                        m_hoverCraft.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
                        m_hoverCraft.setTag(new float[]{1.0f,0.5f});
                        Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
                                0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
                                0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        showHoverView(vw,anim);
                    }
                }
        );
        //hm8.setOnHoverListener(heatMapHover);
        m_views.add(hm8);

        HeatMapElementView hm9 = (HeatMapElementView)view.findViewById(R.id.hmEle_09);
        hm9.setTag(new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(1),Integer.valueOf(3)});
        hm9.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View vw){
                        if(isAnimating)
                            return;

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)m_hoverCraft.getLayoutParams();

                        //int xColumn = ((Integer[])vw.getTag())[0].intValue();
                        relParams.leftMargin = (int)vw.getX();

                        int yRow = ((Integer[])vw.getTag())[1].intValue();
                        relParams.topMargin = ((int)(vw.getHeight()*yRow) - (vw.getHeight()/2) - 162);

                        m_hoverCraft.setTag(new float[]{0.0f,0.5f});
                        m_hoverCraft.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);
                        Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
                                0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
                                0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        showHoverView(vw,anim);
                    }
                }
        );
        //hm9.setOnHoverListener(heatMapHover);
        m_views.add(hm9);

        HeatMapElementView hm10 = (HeatMapElementView)view.findViewById(R.id.hmEle_10);
        hm10.setTag(new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(2),Integer.valueOf(3)});
        hm10.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View vw){
                        if(isAnimating)
                            return;

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)m_hoverCraft.getLayoutParams();

                        //int xColumn = ((Integer[])vw.getTag())[0].intValue();
                        relParams.leftMargin = (int)vw.getX() + (int)vw.getWidth()/2 - 225;

                        int yRow = ((Integer[])vw.getTag())[1].intValue();
                        relParams.topMargin = ((int)(vw.getHeight()*yRow) - (vw.getHeight()/2) - 162);

                        m_hoverCraft.setTag(new float[]{0.5f,0.5f});
                        m_hoverCraft.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
                                0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
                                0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, // Pivot point of X scaling
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        showHoverView(vw,anim);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap one of those blocks into simple for loop..you can for example create an object containing all your variables and create an array of those objects..
Or you can create arrays of floats (or whatever else)..like this

```
int params[] =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  //your code
  // .
  // .
  // .
  someFunctionWithParameter(params[i]);
  // .
  // .
  //.

}
```